# G does not have to be isomorphic to direct product of trivially intersecting normal subgroups of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

From Dan Saracino, abstract algebra (Exercise 14.8)

> Let $G_1,...,G_n$ be subgroups of G such that:
>
> i) $G_1,...,G_n$ are all normal;
>
> ii) $G = G_1.G_2...G_n$, that is, every element of G can be written as $g_l.g_2...g_n$, with $ g_i \in G_i$;
>
> iii) for $1\leq i\leq n$, $G_i\cap G_1 G_2 . . G_{i-1}=\{e\}$.
>
> Show that $G\cong G_1 \times G_2 \times \dots \times G_n$

I have proved the above, but I am not able to find a counterexample for the below statement.

Show, by an example, that if we replace (iii) by the weaker
condition $G_i\cap G_j = \{e\}$ for $i \neq j$, then G does not have to be isomorphic to
$\cong G_1 \times G_2 \times \dots \times G_n$

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$ and `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.

Comment: Well there is an example in which $G$ has order $4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $C_2\times C_2$ contains three proper nontrivial subgroups, any two of which intersect trivially. But the direct product of all of them has order $8$.